# Dygraphs: It is possible to add custom text associated with highlighted point in labels?

Tags: dygraphs

I need to annotate points with some additional text. Since every dot will be annotated, I don't want to add a graphic icon for the annotation of each dot, since this will clobber the drawing.
I'd like that when a dot is highlighted a label shows the associated text.
Also it would be great if the text could be read from a CSV file.

IS this possible? Has anybody modified the library to provide this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck doing this with a [highlightCallback](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#highlightCallback) or [pointClickCallback](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#pointClickCallback) than using annotations. You'll have to do the mapping from point→annotation yourself.